# How to access state when passing parameters using Stack Navigator in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, stack-navigator

I've been working on my first React Native project. It is a Multiscreen App, and one of the screens requires some data, which I'm passing from the parent screen. But the issue is that when I receive the data in the child screen, and try to save the value in the screen's state, the app crashes. As soon as I remove the code that accesses the state, it does not crash. Here's the code:

```
    renderRow(object) {  //Calling the second screen when the user touches
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

    return(
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigate('ViewRecord', { key: object.key })}> //Sending the parameter
        <Image
          styleName="large-square"
          source={{ uri: object.record.image }} >

          <Text style={styles.designNumberHeading}>{object.record.designNumber}</Text>
        </Image>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
```

Here is the code of the Child Screen:

```
    'use-strict'

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Text,
  FlatList,
} from 'react-native';
import {
  Heading,
  Title,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  Image,
  NavigationBar,
  ListView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Icon,
  Lightbox,
  Overlay,
} from '@shoutem/ui';
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view';

import NavBar from '../components/NavBar.js';

import { firebaseApp } from '../config/firebase.js';

export default class ViewRecord extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state={
      designNumber: '',
      dates: [],
      quantity: 0,
      karigars: [],
      colour:'',
      amount: '',
      description: '',
      editMode: false,
    };

    this.updateStateAfterGettingData = this.updateStateAfterGettingData.bind(this);
  }

  getData() {
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;  //Accessing the parameters

    console.log('Key: ', params.key);

    let databaseRef = firebaseApp.database().ref(params.key);

    databaseRef.once('value', (snap) => {
      console.log('Inside Event Listener');

      this.updateStateAfterGettingData(snap);  //Setting the state. (The App crashes if this statement is executed)
    });
  }

  updateStateAfterGettingData(snap) {
    this.setState({
      designNumber: snap.val().designNumber,
      dates: snap.val().dates,
      quantity: snap.val().quantity,
      karigars: snap.val().karigars,
      colour: snap.val().colour,
      amount: snap.val().amount,
      materials: snap.val().materials,
      description: snap.val().description,
    });

    console.log(this.state);
  }

  render() {
    const { goBack } = this.props.navigation;

    this.getData();

    if (!this.state.editMode) {
      return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <NavBar title="View Record" hasHistory={true} goBack={() => goBack()}/>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
  },
})
```

Here is the code of the StackNavigator:

```
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import CreateRecord from '../screens/CreateRecord.js';
import Records from '../screens/Records.js';
import ViewRecord from '../screens/ViewRecord.js';

export const Navigator = StackNavigator({
  Records: { screen: Records },
  CreateRecord: { screen: CreateRecord },
  ViewRecord: { screen: ViewRecord },
},
{
  headerMode: 'none',
  navigationOptions: {
    headerVisible: false,
  }
 });
```

Now, how can I manipulate the state of the ViewRecord.js class when accepting parameters?

PS: I am using Expo along with Create React Native App

Comment: What's the error you get on crash?

Comment: I did not get any error in the console. The app froze for a minute and the entire Expo app crashed. (I am testing my app in an iPhone 6S)

Comment: Run package manager without the Expo app. ```npm start``` should do it. Watch the logs for errors